# How to parse json with json string as value

Tags: node.js, json

One of the values in my json object is a string that represents json. How do I parse it in node.js? How can I represent a json string as a value in a json object? It seems to be failing on the first curly bracket within the string.

**example:**

```
> json = '{"t":"{\"a\":1,\"b\":\"a sample text\"}","c":2,"r":"some text"}'
> JSON.parse(json)

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 8
```

**expected:**

```
{
  t: '{a:1,b:"a sample text"}',
  c: 2,
  r: 'some text'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the extra unnecessary characters and then parse the json. I just did some reverse engineering in order to parse it.

```js
let json = '{"t":"{\"a\":1,\"b\":\"a sample text\"}","c":2,"r":"some text"}'

const parsedJson = JSON.parse(json.replace(/\\"/g,"").replace(/"{/g, "{").replace(/}"/g, "}"))

console.log(parsedJson)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's great in order to parse the string, but that doesn't help me know how to represent a json string as a value in the original json.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in order to represent this json string as a value in the json object, I had to use double slashes to escape the quotes:

```
> json = '{"t":"{a:1,b:\\"a sample text\\"}","c":2,"r":"some text"}'
> JSON.parse(json)
{ t: '{a:1,b:"a sample text"}', c: 2, r: 'some text' }
```